# Do I need my Windows 7 license key to do a Windows 8 upgrade?

Tags: windows

I don't have my Windows 7 license key.  I upgraded to the Windows 8 preview and now I am having problems with my computer because it says my preview expired and it keeps shutting it off.

I see you can buy a Windows 8 upgrade for $40.  But someone told me I'll need my Windows 7 license.  Is this true, or can I just put the upgrade on and have it work?

Comment: If you have Windows 8 Release Preview installed you just use the upgrade tool to perform the installation.

Comment: Are you saying I won't need to enter the key?

Answer (score -1):

When you use an upgrade version of Windows, you need to have a valid licence for a previous, eligible version of Windows. That licence is not freed up for use on another computer after the upgrade.

Comment: This doesn't go into enough detail.  For instance Windows an eligible version is the Release Preview of Windows 8.

Comment: Are you saying I need the actual key?  Or is it okay if I lose it but the machine is one with a verified license?

Comment: @Joe - You need to run the installer from within Windows to determine your eligability.